# SDL errors Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and SDL 2.0.1, and for some reason, I get a whole bunch of errors similar to this:

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_DestroyWindow referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall Display::~Display(void)" (??1Display@@UAE@XZ)   c:\Users\Toby\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\OpenGLTutorialProject\OpenGLTutorialProject\Display.obj OpenGLTutorialProject
```

The steps I took to link SDL to my program:
-Created a folder called include, and put all the files in SDL/include into my project's include folder.
-Created a lib folder for my project, and put all the contents in SDL/lib into it.
-Went to **Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories** and pointed it to my lib folder in the project.
-Went to **Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> AdditionalInclude Directories** and set the path to my include folder in my project.
-Went to **Properties -> Linker -> Input-> Additional Dependencies** and typed the following:

```
glew32.lib
glew32s.lib
SDL2.lib
SDL2main.lib
SDL2test.lib
OpenGL32.lib
```

Yes, I also included GLEW, which works fine and links.

When I type this:

```
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
```

Visual studio actually completes it for me, so visual studio knows SDL exists in the project. However, after that, I try to run and compile, and I'm met with a bunch of unresolved external symbol errors, and then this:

```
Error   12  error LNK1120: 11 unresolved externals  c:\users\toby\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\OpenGLTutorialProject\Debug\OpenGLTutorialProject.exe   OpenGLTutorialProject
```

I searched and it seems SDL used to have trouble with visual studio 2013, but then the bugs were ironed out. I also made sure to set up my main method like so:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Because I have heard SDL is picky when it comes to arguments in the main method. Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: I would really appreciate some help...

Comment: By the way, you should not have `glew32.lib` and `glew32s.lib` both as dependencies for your software. One (glew32) is the DLL import library and the other is static (glew32s). If you `#define GLEW_STATIC` before including `glew.h` (and I suggest you do, as the DLL version does not offer any real benefit) link against `glew32s.lib`, otherwise link against `glew32.lib` and remember to distribute the GLEW DLL with your software.

Comment: Sorry, I just started following a tutorial I found. I quite honestly am very new to C++, although not new to programming @AndonM.Coleman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are either using a incorrect path or linking against the wrong version of the libraries for your selected platform? ie x86 or x64?

If your compiler is set up for 32-bit you need to use the x86 libraries and not the x64.

Also, the `Additional Library Directories` needs to point at the directory where the lib files are located, in SDL2 the lib directory has two sub directories for x86 and x64 respectively. If you copied everything from the SDL lib directory the files might have ended up where they shouldn't be.

Comment: I only copied the x64 version of the files, so that wouldn't be the issue. How can I find out what type of compiler I have? I use Visual Studio (obviously), and I am on a x64 computer. Does that mean I have a x64 compiler?

Comment: @opiop65 And you have VS set to use the X64 configuration in the configuration manager? If I remember correctly it defaults to x86 (Win32). The target platform isn't tied to your OS version, VS can compile for both X64 and X86 and your computer can run both.

Try changing to the X86 SDL libraries in the lib directory and you'll most likely be fine.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! I had to switch over to x86 DLLs and I had to remove the static GLEW DLL! After that everything worked great, thanks!

Comment: @opiop65 happy to have helped :)

Comment: Hmm... I'm having so trouble here. When I try to use the x86 SDL2.lib file, the compiler prints out unresolved symbol errors. But when I use the x64 version of the .lib file, it compiles, but does not run... Is there a bug in the x86 version?

Comment: @Charlie You should post your question as a new question really so it gets the attention needed, and also include some details.